# babel es6 wrong exception location with react

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

i think this is a babel problem (not completely sure).  The errors my javascript console throws are always wrong...  No matter where the error occurs in my code it points to my handleFailure(serviceName, error) block...   for instance... Calling this.foo(); after hand success occurs or even in i move this.foo(); to my getItemById method.. it always throws an error in the same block...  What am i doing wrong in my store....

if i remove the bogus code it works just fine...  i would like the error shown to me to reference the bogus code..

**this is the error:**
    AircraftLocationStore.js:40 Server call aircraftLocationRest failed with error: aircraftLocationRest!handleFailure @ AircraftLocationStore.js:40(anonymous function) @ RestServiceClient.js:20

```
class AircraftLocationStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.NOT_REQUESTED;
        this._dataStore = Map({});
        this.handleSuccess = this.handleSuccess.bind(this);
        this.handleFailure = this.handleFailure.bind(this);
    }
    populate(){
        RestService.fetchData(this.handleSuccess, this.handleFailure, 'aircraftLocationRest');
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.STARTED
    }

    handleSuccess(serviceName, jsonData){
        UT.logMethod(TAG, `${serviceName} succeeded!`)
        jsonData.forEach((entity) => {
            let tempEntity = AircraftLocationHelper.createFromJson(entity);
            this._dataStore = this._dataStore.merge(Map.of(tempEntity.id, tempEntity))
        });
        UT.log('isMap', Map.isMap(this._dataStore))
        this.foo();
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.SUCCESS;
        this.emitChange();
    }

    handleFailure(serviceName, error){
        //Utils.logMethod(TAG, 'handleFailure');
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.FAILED
        console.error(`Server call ${serviceName} failed with error: ${serviceName}!`)
    }

  ...

export default new AircraftLocationStore();
```

if i try and change an immutablejs record on my display component in the onChange it tells me this...

just in case i will include the code that handles the callback that ALWAYS throws the error

```
class RestServiceClient{

    /**
     * @param successCB
     * @param failureCB
     * @param endPoint
     */
    fetchData(successCB, failureCB, endPoint) {
        const serverUrl = BASE_URL + endPoint;
        UT.log('serverUrl', serverUrl);
        fetch(serverUrl).then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => successCB(endPoint, data))
            .catch(e => failureCB(endPoint, e.toString()))
    }
}
export default new RestServiceClient();
```

here is my webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: You'll have much more luck if you trim this down to a smaller example. You also haven't told us what error gets thrown.

Comment: i just included it.... i wanted to be less verbose but i have no idea where it is stemming from.... whenever an error occurs anywhere in my project, it references that line i mentioned...    its bizzarre...

Comment: I get what you're saying, but SO is a site for answering specific questions, it's still your responsibility to provide us with enough information to answer the question. Sometimes posting a bunch of code isn't the end of the world because the problem is clear, but here you haven't really given us much to go on, you've essentially just asked "fix this for me". Start deleting functions and inlining until you get a small example to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem appeared to be in my anonymous function that was created by the fat arrows =>

i rewrote:

```
    fetch(serverUrl).then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => let foo = data; successCB(endPoint, data))
        .catch(e => failureCB(endPoint, e.toString()));
```

as:

```
fetch(serverUrl)
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        failureCB(endPoint, 'Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
                    }
                    // Examine the text in the response
                    response.json().then(function(data) {
                        successCB(endPoint, data)
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function(err) {
                failureCB(endPoint, 'Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + err);
         });
```

and i once again have some meaningfull error messages...